# Using Vuex with Nuxt and Vue-Native-Websocket

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm trying to fill my vuex store with data from websocket. I'm using Nuxt. For handling websocket I'm using vue-native-websocket package. Connection to websocket is successful, but commiting to the store doesn't work, it fires an error on every socket event `Uncaught TypeError: this.store[n] is not a function`

According to Nuxt and vue-native-websocket docs, I've using them as following:

Plugin native-websocket.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueNativeSock from 'vue-native-websocket'
import store from '~/store'

Vue.use(VueNativeSock, 'wss://dev.example.com/websocket/ws/connect', { store: store })
```

nuxt.config.js

```
  plugins: [
   {src: '~plugins/native-websocket.js', ssr: false}
],
```

As the connection is established, I draw a conclusion that the package is connected right, so it's something about store and I can't get what's wrong

UPD: After some workaround I've found out that logging store inside native-websocket.js returns

```
store() {
  return new __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_vuex__["default"].Store({
   state: {...my store
```

and commiting to it returns `__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__store__.default.commit is not a function`
So it's something about webpack as I can see

Comment: Use a callback as the 3rd argument instead, `passToStoreHandler: function (eventName, event) {`, inside of here log out `this.store` what is the value

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I've tried just now, console is clear, callback doesn't fire

`{
  passToStoreHandler: function(eventName, event) {
    console.log(this.store);
    console.log('test')
  }}`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Sorry, I've forgot pass the store to that object. Now console.log returns my `store()`, but there is no error only if callback is passed to third argument object. No commits are made to store anyway

Comment: Maybe try building the commit yourself and committing to the store. Does that work?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Tried `this.store.commit('incrementCounter')` inside of `passToStoreHandler`. 
Got `this.store.commit is not a function`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to import store differently e.g. get it from context of plugin. Here some [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#inject-in-root-amp-context), but they somewhat lacking

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueNativeSock from 'vue-native-websocket'

export default ({ store }, inject) => {
  Vue.use(VueNativeSock, 'wss://dev.example.com/websocket/ws/connect', { store: store })
}
```